# HTML's input type = button not clickable in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, button

I've got the problem that a few buttons are only clickable in the upper ~25% of the button, the pointer doesn't appear anywhere below this mark.
I tried some things and when I changed it in CSS to `display: block` and the whole button became clickable again, but when I tried `display: inline-block` it bugs again beeing not clickable.

However this **only** happens in Chrome, works fine in IE and Firefox. And the **back** button works aswell as whole, just those three asigned to class *buttonRot* ain't working.. Whats wrong here?

Here's my code : 
[HTML]

```
<form method="POST" action="zumtesten7.php" style="background-color:white">
<input type="button" value="Jetzt freigeben" name="Speichern" onClick="doSubmit(this.form,<?php echo (int) $intSNr.','.$BuchungsNr ?>)" class="buttonRot">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Stornieren" name="Storno" onClick="doStorno(this.form,<?php echo $intSNr.','.$BuchungsNr ?>)" class="buttonRot">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Seite drucken" name="Drucken" onClick="javascript:window.print()" class="buttonRot">
<input type="button" value="Zurück" name="Back" onClick="javascript:window.location.href='zumtesten6.php?SNr=<?php echo $intSNr;?>'" class="buttonBlau"  style="margin-left: 592px;margin-top:-20px">
```

[CSS]

```
.buttonRot {
    padding: 0 5px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    width:auto;
    height:22px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#cc0000;
    color:#ffffff;
}

.buttonBlau is the same just with  

background-color:#00aaee;
```

I guess it has to do something with the form?
I changed the bg-color at the first line to black to be visible and only the 3 red ones were in it.
Those are the bugged ones, the blue wasn't in it and works.

Edit: This **marked area** is clickable https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCfKB.jpg and the outer bottom line of the button,
but you have to be super pixel-precise..
Edit 2 : Tried to increase the padding, which was clickable.. 
Seems like the text isn't clickable, the padding top and bottom are clickable. I'm confused.

**Seems like I got rid of it** after `</td></tr>`'ing after the 3 red buttons and opening new ones for the blue one. I don't know how but it's clickable as whole again.. worked aswell after I tried to remove the margin only. Sometimes programming is confusing. :(

Comment: I pasted your provided markup & CSS to jsfiddle but I can't reproduce your problem. May you edit your question with a "working" jsfiddle to reproduce the problem?

Comment: that's what I dont get, I tried to jsfiddle it to a friend of mine who knows css better than me, but it worked in fiddle..

Comment: Just last week I had a similar problem (in all browsers) with some specific links on a page where you could only click on the bottom half of the text. In my case it turned out there was an image overlapping the top of the links, but the background of the image was transparent so you could not see that it overlapped. (And as long as we're talking fiddles, I too tried putting your code in a fiddle and couldn't reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5bT69/)

Comment: I edited a picture with the clickable area in chrome.

Comment: try adding -webkit-appearance: none; and z-index: 999;

Comment: seems like nothing changed.. :/

Comment: maybe the problem is about the version of your browser

Comment: I've tried it on the actual chrome version on Win8 and Win XP, didn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i'm sorry i can't jsut comment).

Your problem it's probably the padding rule. Try to change to check if click-able area changes too.